# Ant build tool installation not working properly!

Tags: ant

i have downloaded the Ant distribution from the Ant web site.
apache-ant-1.7.0
and set environment variable specifying the location of the Ant installationas
ANT_HOME = C:\portal\apache-ant-1.7.0

PATH=;%ANT_HOME%\bin

But ant is not getting properly installed

Answer (score 2):

Better use batch or shell scripts to start your ant files, f.e. =

windows

```
  set JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk\1.6.0_xx
  set ANT_HOME=C:\ant
  set ANT_ARGS=-lib C:\ant_xtralibs;C:\ant_testlibs
  set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\cvsnt

  :: default
  call ant -f %1

  :: debug
  ::call ant -debug -f %1
  ...
```

unix - don't forget the quotationmarks on the ANT_ARGS line !

```
  ...
  ANT_ARGS="-lib /usr/local/ant_xtralibs:/usr/local/ant_testlibs"
  export ANT_ARGS
  ...
```

Some advantages of starting ant like that :

- ANT_ARGS is a special environment variable. Its content is automatically
  added to the invocation of ant.
- you may use your own ant settings on a machine where you have no admin rights
- using a separate folder for your ant addon libs and load via -lib option
  keeps your ant installation clean and avoids polluting the %ANT_HOME%/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

Move the ';' to the end. Be sure that java is also correct installed (variable for classpath, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you verson of windows (win2k & win XP), you might need to reboot your computer to make your PATH modifications taken into account.