# How can I override libs/ as the location of my Android 3rd party libraries in my ant build?

Tags: android, ant

If I put my 3rd party jars in libs/ then I can build my project using ant. However, I can't figure out how to change that location to something else. For example, if I put my jars in libs/main I can't get my build to find them. I've tried the following properties with no luck:

- `jar.libs.dir=libs/main`
- `external.libs.dir=libs/main`

I tried putting those in both the xml and in the `ant.properties` files with no luck. What property can I set to override the libs directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you asked because of Ant addon task not working :
Use `ANT_ARGS` for that purpose, i.e. use in it a batchfile/shellscript to run your ant script,
 [see that answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291692/130683).
Otherwise if compilation of sources fails use `<javac>` with nested `<classpath>` :

```
<javac ...>
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="lib/"/>
    <pathelement path=".../"/>
  </classpath>
</javac>
```

examples here => http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html
and here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/722787/130683

Comment: Where am I to put this javac declaration? I was hoping to just override a path, not copy and modify the existing compile task.